# Table with lot of fields , or table with 1 to 1 relation for search performance

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a master table with about 100 fields . 
In my application there are lot of search queries involve lot of these fields and other child/lookup tables fields.
In database concept as I know it's advised to separate fields according to their logical groups.But in my case this will generate about 10 tables with one to one relation (ie: using lot of join queries when searching).
So I am afraid that this database design slows down search performance .

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, do not separate the columns into multiple tables unless there is some very clear and specific benefit to doing so. There is none in your case, nor in the great majority of cases.

Comment: I have to disagree, having a very large table can bring your SQL server to a crawl on simple queries. I suggest using caching tables, that can be updated from a MySQL event or trigger for speed performance.

Comment: There may be a specific issue with wide tables on particular platforms that counts as a "very clear and specific benefit" for that implementation (is there explicit guidance on the circumstances?), but the starting assumption ought to be that you do not vertically partition tables. Actually, if a particular architecture has some problem wit wide tables then my first choice would be to move to an RDBMS that is not inherently crippled in such a strange way. PostgreSQL would be a fine choice.